# Проблема с вызовом функции-члена (не меняет состояние переданного объекта)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, ооп, классы

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class monstr {
private:
    int hp;
    int dmg;
public:
    monstr() {
        hp = rand()%50+50;
        dmg = rand() % 10 + 10;
    }


    monstr(int _hp, int _dmg) {
        hp = _hp;
        dmg = _dmg;
    }


    int get_hp() {
        return hp;
    }


    int get_dmg() {
        return dmg;
    }


    void set_hp(int _hp) {
        hp = _hp;
    }


    void set_dmg(int _dmg) {
        dmg = _dmg;
    }


    void say_info() {
        cout << "------------" << endl;
        cout << "|  hp=" << hp << "     |" << endl;
        cout<< "|  dmg=" << dmg <<"    |"<< endl;       
        cout << "--------------" << endl<<endl;
    }


    int attack(monstr a) {
        a.set_hp(hp) -= a.set_dmg();
       // a.hp -=  a.dmg;
        //return a.set_hp(hp);
         a.get_hp();
    }
};
int main()
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    vector <monstr> a(10);
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        cout << i + 1 << ":";
        a[i].say_info();
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        a[i].attack(a[i+1]);
        cout << i + 1 << ":";
        a[i].say_info();
}
return 0;
```

Comment: скорее всего здесь ошибка: a.set_hp(hp) -= a.set_dmg();

Answer (score 3):

Вы передаете в функцию монстра по значению:

```
int attack(monstr a) {
```

т.е. создается *копия* монстра. Которой и наносится урон. По выходу из функции копия исчезает, а исходный монстр остается нетронутым. Такой "бой с тенью" получается :)

Попробуйте

```
int attack(monstr& a) {
```

Еще - ваши функции `void`, так что если уж хотите через геттеры-сеттеры, то:

```
a.set_hp(a.get_hp() - a.get_dmg());
```

Ну и, видимо, вы забыли `rewturn` перед `a.get_hp();`...

P.S. У вас так и задумано, что при атаке атакующий монстр (объект `*this`) не получает никакого урона, только атакуемый?..

Comment: Спасибо за подсказку, пойду проверю. По идее здесь получается цепочка, где первый бьет ворого, второй третьего...девятый десятого. Позже я сделаю так, чтобы десятый бил первого, но это потом.

Comment: Ну, у вас еще проблема в том, что ваши функции ничего не возвращают. И вам надо раскомментировать строку `a.hp -=  a.dmg;` и убрать `a.set_hp(hp) -= a.set_dmg();` - тем более что в ней вы объекту `a` пытаетесь дать значение `hp` объекта `*this`.

Comment: я попробовал сделать так, как вы сказали, но ничего не изменилось. возможно ошибка еще в чем-то

Comment: все получилось, спасибо

Comment: Спасибо здесь принимает форму принятого ответа :)